# Python pandas find the column names in descending order for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below pandas data frame and I am trying to find the column names in descending order for each row.

`A  B  C  D
A 1  3  2  1
B 2  1  5  0
C 1  0  1  9
D 2  0  1  2`

For each row I am trying to get the column indexes in sorted order ( descending ) 
I should get :

`B C D A
C A B D`

and so on
Is this possible using pandas.?

I am trying something like this.

`test[2].sort_index(axis = 0, ascending = True)`

Update 12/23

```
>>> df1
user_handle  1   2   3   4   5   6   8   9   10  12
user_handle
1             6   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
2             0  95   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
3             0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4             1   0   0  12   0   1   0   0   2   0
5             0   1   0   0   9   0   0   0   0   0
6             0   0   0   1   0  14   0   0   1   0
8             0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0
9             0   0   0   0   0   0   0  12   0   0
10            0   1   0   2   0   1   0   0  49   0
12            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2

>>> t1 = np.flip(df1.values.argsort(), 1)


>>> pd.DataFrame(df1.columns[t1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 303, in __init__
    dtype=dtype)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 411, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5506, in _arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4310, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2792, in __init__
    (block.ndim, self.ndim))
AssertionError: Number of Block dimensions (3) must equal number of axes (2)
>>>
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Post the code you've attempted so far.

Comment: I have pasted the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use :

```
temp = np.flip(df.values.argsort(),1)
ndf = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[temp])

   0  1  2  3
0  B  C  D  A
1  C  A  B  D
2  D  C  A  B
3  D  A  C  B
```

Comment: me too!  `flipud` looks useful.

Comment: Pl check your output

Comment: @Vaishali I updated, I dont know why I used flipud inplace of flip, such misunderstand of the function

Comment: @andrew_reece I had misunderstood the function, we have to use `flip` here, flipud reverses both columns as well as rows.

Comment: This seems to be the fastest

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: Thank You Dark and all others for the help.

Comment: There is one issue that I see in Python 3.6 though.  `   mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2792, in __init__
    (block.ndim, self.ndim))
AssertionError: Number of Block dimensions (3) must equal number of axes (2)

`

Comment: And where did this come??  I mean executing which line

Comment: I added the details in the original question, as there is a 60 word limit in comments.

Comment: @renjithmadhavan I'm unable to reproduce the error in my PC. Its working fine. Try updating the pandas version and try once again

Comment: Thanks @Dark . My pandas version is 0.20.3 and numpy is at 1.13.3 . I will upgrade and will give a try again.

Comment: I upgraded pandas to latest 0.21.1 , its still the same error. What version of pandas and numpy are you using.

Comment: I am able to workaround this by creating the dataframe like this though.   
   df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df1.columns[t1])

Answer (score 4):

By using `rank` and `unstack`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).rank(method ='first',ascending =False).reset_index(level=1).set_index(0,append=True).unstack()
Out[309]: 
  level_1            
0     1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
A       B   C   A   D
B       C   A   B   D
C       D   A   C   B
D       A   D   C   B
```

And using `numpy`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.columns.values[np.lexsort(([df.columns.values]*len(df),df.values))]).iloc[:, ::-1]
Out[351]: 
   3  2  1  0
0  B  C  D  A
1  C  A  B  D
2  D  C  A  B
3  D  A  C  B
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `argsort()` and then index into `columns`:

```
(df.apply(lambda x: (-x).argsort(), axis=1) # use -x for sort descending
   .apply(lambda x: df.columns[x], axis=1))

   A  B  C  D
A  B  C  A  D
B  C  A  B  D
C  D  A  C  B
D  A  D  C  B
```

Note: If you don't want the index and columns in your final output, just add `.values`.

Answer (score 3):

Using numpy argsort,

```
pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)])


    0   1   2   3
0   B   C   A   D
1   C   A   B   D
2   D   A   C   B
3   A   D   C   B
```

Comment: I dont understand the purpose of `[:, :df.shape[1]]`, It would return the same if you dont use that